# Improving a Rubik's Cube scrambler's byte count

Tags: code-golf, tips, javascript

Okay, I recently wrote a Javascript Rubik's Cube scrambler that outputs a 25-move scramble. It's 135 bytes. The Gist is [here](https://gist.github.com/molarmanful/2f299ae96f6120cf5283), but for reference, I have the formatted code:

```js
function(){
  for(a=s=y=r=[],m='RLUDFB',x=Math.random;++a<26;y=r,s.push(r+["'",2,''][0|x()*2]))
  for(;r==y;r=m[0|x()*5]);
  return s.join(' ')
}
```

Any tips?

EDIT: Code is updated, with @Optimizer's edits.

Comment: I am assuming that you need to run this in browser, so ES5 and below only ?

Comment: Some of the answers are likely to be complete rewrites rather than tips for lowering the byte count of your algorithm/implementation.

Comment: @Optimizer Yeah, you have to run in a browser console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## <s>140 135</s> 127 bytes

Still a big one, but here's for starters:

```js
function(){for(a=s=y=r=[],x=Math.random;a<25;s[a++]=r+["'",2,''][0|x(y=r)*3])for(;r==y;r='RLUDFB'[0|x()*6]);return s.join(' ')}
```

Some of the few tips used:

- Loose the `var`. There is no point in using `var` when your aim is to golf!
- When `a = []`, `a++` gives `0`. We use this fact to remove a `0` and `,`
- Combine the `a<25` and `a++`
- You don't need to split a string. You can access its characters anyways via `[i]`
- Get rid of `{}` in `for` loops

More to come.

Comment: Just wondering, why are the parentheses after the function not there?

Comment: @molarmanful Whoops